# WinPCAP C++ Sending packet

Tags: c++, c, tcp, winpcap

So, I want send packet over TCP by using by pcap_sendpacket

```
TCP_Packet.Set_Ethernet_Source_MAC(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
TCP_Packet.Set_Ethernet_Destination_MAC(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2);
TCP_Packet.Set_Ethernet_Type(0x0800);
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_Version(4);
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_IHL(5);
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_ToS(0);
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_Total_Length(sizeof(IPv4_Address_s) + sizeof(TCP_s));
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_Identification(2);
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_Flag(0);
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_Offset(0);
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_Live_Time(0x80);
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_Protocol(0x06);
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_Checksum(0);
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_Destination_Address(192, 168, 1, 2);
TCP_Packet.Set_IPv4_Source_Address(192, 168, 1, 2);

TCP_Packet.Set_TCP_Destination_Port(45578); //In method is htons
TCP_Packet.Set_TCP_Source_Port(45578); //In method is htons
TCP_Packet.Set_TCP_Sequence_Number(0);
TCP_Packet.Set_TCP_Acknowledgment_Number(0);
TCP_Packet.Set_TCP_Flag_SYN(1);
TCP_Packet.Set_TCP_Offset(5);
TCP_Packet.Set_TCP_Window_Size(64240);
TCP_Packet.Set_TCP_Checksum(0);
TCP_Packet.Set_TCP_Urgent_Pointer(0);
if (FAILURE == TCP_Packet.Send_Packet(Capture_Instance)) //Here is all good
{
    cerr << "Can't send packet: " << pcap_geterr(Capture_Instance) << endl;
    return FAILURE;
}
else
    cout << "Sended" << endl;
```

Problem: It seems to not working. The server doesn't detect any packets on port 45578 and wireshark too, but it should work.

Comment: The mac addresses in the first two lines don't look valid or did you edit that out?

Comment: MAC is valid, but I edited it for question.

Comment: Can you "play" w/ the _source_ port ?

Comment: Hi. You'll not see the packet if you stay local.

The source address and the destination address are the same and wireshark will not see them.

If you want to see the packets in wireshark then test with the server and the client on different computers, or at least different interface bindings.